# sql: display result when condition count(ill)<=5

Tags: sql, count

i want to generate a report about the special illness report that with condition number of count of illness more than or equal 5.The sql query cannot run :

```
select 
   a.treatid 
  ,b.patid 
  ,b.patname
  ,b.tel
  ,a.ill
  ,count(a.ill) 
from treatment a, 
     patient a 
where a.patid=b.patid 
 and count(ill)<=5;
```

the query did not generate result as i expected. 
but generate all treatment with `count(ill) =1` .

anyone can help me to solve this problem.

i already tired in testing this query.

Comment: why are both alias' set as `a`?

Answer (score 4):

Because you have count(A.ill) in your select statement - you will need to use the having clause in conjunction with a group by. 
For example:

```
SELECT b.patid, b.patname, b.tel, a.ill, count(a.ill) 
FROM treatment a 
INNER JOIN patient b ON a.patid=b.patid
GROUP BY a.ill, b.patid, b.patname, b.tel 
HAVING count(a.ill)<=5;
```

Comment: generate same result as the question